# Want nondetects to show on ggplot figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like my nondetects to show on my graph (so it doesn't just look like no data was collected at a particular location on a particular date).  I was thinking of making them triangles?  I am not sure that I have my csv set up correctly, or that I am using the right commands. I appreciate any insight.

Note: I put 0 in the "Results" column for the nondetects and in the "Detects" column I assigned a 1 to all detects and a 0 to all nondetects. I think this may be part of my issue-but I'm not sure how to resolve it...
Here is my code:

## Example Data

```
Date       Reservoir           Result    Detects
9/24/2019  Epilimnion          0.2       1
9/24/2019  Metalimnion         0.6       1
9/24/2019  Hypolimnion         1.8       1
10/8/2019  Epilimnion          0         0
10/8/2019  Metalimnion         1.9       1
10/8/2019  Hypolimnion         3.7       1
10/22/2019  Epilimnion         0         0
10/22/2019  Metalimnion        0         0
10/22/2019  Hypolimnion        2.7       1

    TN<-read.csv("TN.csv", header=TRUE)
    library(lubridate)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(scales)
ggplot(TN, aes(x = mdy(Date), y = Result, color = Reservoir, pch=ifelse(Detects, 19, 17), cex = 1.5))+
  geom_point(size = 4)+
  ylab("Total Nitrogen (mg/L)") +
  scale_x_date(name = "", breaks = date_breaks("1 month"), labels = date_format("%b %Y"), 
               limits = c(mdy("08/30/2019"),mdy("1/10/2020"))) + 
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c("Hypolimnion", "Metalimnion (Bottom)", "Metalimnion (Top)", "Epilimnion"),
                       breaks = c("Hypolimnion", "Metalimnion (Bottom)", "Metalimnion (Top)", "Epilimnion")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1.0, hjust = 1.0, size=12,), axis.text.y = element_text(size=12), axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=3, size=12, face="bold"),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with this code that you want to change? Note that `ggplot` doesn't have an `pch=` or `cex=` mapping. You probably want `shape=` and `size=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is informative:

```
Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape
```

Which refers to the pch argument:

```
pch=ifelse(Detects, 19, 17)
```

And as MrFlick mentioned, this is what ggplot calls a `shape`. The numbers 19 and 17 may look discrete to a human eye, but they are actually continuous (=numeric) to a computer (in this case R). Discrete in ggplot sense meaning categorical (=factor). So, mutate this variable into a factor, use it directly as the `shape` argument (btw `pch` works too) and Bob's your uncle:

```
TN %>%
  mutate(Detects=factor(Detects)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mdy(Date), y = Result, color = Reservoir, pch=Detects), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(size = 4)+
  ylab("Total Nitrogen (mg/L)") +
  scale_x_date(name = "", breaks = date_breaks("1 month"), labels = date_format("%b %Y"), 
               limits = c(mdy("08/30/2019"),mdy("1/10/2020"))) + 
  #scale_color_discrete(labels = c("Hypolimnion", "Metalimnion (Bottom)", "Metalimnion (Top)", "Epilimnion"),
  #                     breaks = c("Hypolimnion", "Metalimnion (Bottom)", "Metalimnion (Top)", "Epilimnion")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1.0, hjust = 1.0, size=12,), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=12), axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=3, size=12, face="bold"),
  #      legend.title=element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]
Note that I removed your `scale_color_discrete` override and I recommend not hiding the legend titles.

Comment: It took me a few tries-but I've gotten everything to work now!  Thank you.